# Unable to create registry keys under a specific key

Tags: c++, c, winapi, registry

I am trying to create a key named "colorfiltering" under "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATConfig".
While debugging my program, I realized that the RegCreateKeyExA function is setting the sent HKEY to NULL.

I tried adding a key with another name under that path, but still nothing.
Later on, I tried adding the key under "HKCU\SOFTWARE", then under "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft", then each time I added a following container until Accessibility. All of the test cases succeeded, except ATConfig.

Furthermore, I realized that the DWORD lpdwDisposition the function is passing back, equals 2, which means that the key existed and was simply opened without being changed. But the key didn't exist, neither keys with other names under that path.

**NOTE:** I ran the program always as an administrator.

[RegCreateKeyExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexa)

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define REG_COLORFILTERING_NT "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Accessibility\\ATConfig\\colorfiltering"
#define REG_COLORFILTERING_ATconfig_NT "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Accessibility\\ATConfig"
#define REG_TEST "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Accessibility\\ATConfig\\TEST"

...

HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwDis;
RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_COLORFILTERING_NT, NULL, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hNewKey, &dwDis); // hKey = 0x00000000 <NULL>   ;;;   dwDis = 2
```

Comment: What is the return code of the call? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeya. Could well be 5, since I think you need admin rights to create a key there.

Comment: Hi, GetLastError returned 0

Comment: The call returns 1021

Comment: Never seen that one before :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-

ERROR_CHILD_MUST_BE_VOLATILE 1021 (0x3FD) Cannot create a stable subkey under a volatile parent key. Maybe it means you have to create parent keys first?

Comment: it means you need use `REG_OPTION_VOLATILE` in call `RegCreateKeyEx`

Comment: @RbMm Ah nice, I learned something too then :)

Comment: @RbMm Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: *Is it possible that I am getting blocked by the system from adding keys to that key?* - for what in this case exist error code ? it say reason, not need guess. the reason is clear - in parent key is volatile - any child can nt be permanent

Comment: It is rather annoying that there is no flag to say you don't care if it is volatile or not.

Comment: if we don't care - we always can use REG_OPTION_VOLATILE flag. this is  always ok create volatile sub key - under volatile or not volatile parent. only create not volatile child under volatile parent is error